# What are necessary to study about Schramm Loewner evolution?

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, random-walk

I want to study about Schramm Loewner evolution.

I found many good sources to study about the concept including the lecture notes written by Greg Lawler.

Before studying with those lecture notes, I found that I must have concrete backgrounds in complex analysis and stochastic analysis.

Since I'm an undergraduate student in department of mathematics and statistics, I studied some fundamentals in real analysis and I'm studying basic probability theory and stochastic analysis. In stochastic analysis, what specific concepts are necessary to understand the concept?

I don't have background in complex analysis yet, so I'm planning to study complex analysis. I found that conformal mappings, Riemannian mapping theorem, etc. are crucial. Can I get some suggestions about what to study, and what textbooks are nice to study background knowledge?

Thank you very much for reading and sorry for my poor English skill...

Answer (score 2):

Professor Lawler has written excellent notes on many subjects.

For example, *Introduction to Stochastic Calculus* is well-written.  It can be found on his website.

[https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~lawler/inprogress](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Elawler/inprogress)